# Best way to use Where Clause in SQL SERVER Query (for best performance)?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have written 2 queries in SQL Server and used SUB Query in join with Where Clause, Please let me know which is the best way to do in below Queries.

```
 Query 1. SELECT column1,column2,column3,JOINTAB.column5 FROM Table1 
   INNER JOIN (SELECT column1,column4,column5 FROM Table2 WHERE 
    column4='xxxx') AS JOINTAB ON Table1.column1=JOINTAB.column1

 Query 2. SELECT column1,column2,column3,JOINTAB.column5 FROM Table1 
    INNER JOIN (SELECT column1,column4,column5 FROM Table2) AS JOINTAB
    ON Table1.column1=JOINTAB.column1 WHERE JOINTAB.column4='xxxx'
```

For the best performance Query 1 or 2?

Comment: query 1 will be quick. coz it is fetching filtered record. where clause on join tab after selecting all rows will be time consuming

Comment: Smells like home work questions. And yes, logically speaking option 1 is better since it implies less work overall for providing a filtered set for the outside query. Realistically though, these tend to depend on the DB and indexing. I've seen logically sound ideas like this produce horrible plans in some conditions, quite a few times.

Answer (score 0):

Your best option here is not to use a subquery at all. It's not needed. Either of thsese will give you the same results:

```
SELECT t1.column1,t1.column2,t1.column3,t2.column5 
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t1 on t2.column1 = t1.column1 and t2.column4 = 'xxxx'

--or

SELECT t1.column1,t1.column2,t1.column3,t2.column5 
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t1 on t2.column1 = t1.column1 
WHERE t2.column4 = 'xxxx'
```

Comment: Best performance is to avoid the subquery (as I posted)... if there's any difference at all, that is. the query optimizer will likely rewrite all of these to use the same execution plan.

Comment: Thanks, I have used (in sub query) many tables in my real time query and it was the only way

Answer (score 0):

Query Performance is a great concern for all the developers.
To find the performance and optimization simply you can view 'query execution plans'.

You can use the Query Analyzer, to which execution plan is chosen by the optimizer. Simply type an SQL statement in the Query window and press the Ctrl+L key. The query is displayed graphically.

> SQL Server offers is the ability to see query execution plans

Run the query and find the performance.

[image]